# NetBeans adding external library Vaadin Framework

Tags: netbeans, frameworks, vaadin

How can I add external library to Vaadin framework using NetBeans?
I can't find libraries folder there. Additionally I want use `pi4j` library.

[image]

I haven't seen it there like in normal Java Application Libraries folder.

Comment: How did you add the vaadin libraries to your project's classpath?

Comment: I made Vaadin Web Application project. The libraries was included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Maven. In that case you have to edit your **pom.xml** file (you can find it in the *Project Files* folder in NetBeans).

Google for the Maven coordinates for the library you want to include and add the corresponding dependency section in the **dependencies** section. For example, to add Log4j, you must add the following in your pom.xml:

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

Alternatively, you can right click the *Dependencies* folder in NetBeans, select *Add Dependency...*, and add the corresponding Maven coordinates or search for the dependency (keep in mind the Maven Index may be updated the first time you search for a dependency, process that might take some seconds/minutes).

Comment: Thank You very much. It was answer I excepted.
I used alternatively way and to add it in tree Dependenicies -> myNewDependienices (right click) -> Manually install artifact and browse to library on localdisc and everything works good.